# Bind9 Response Policy ignoring out-of-zone data

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, debian, bind, rpz

I'm trying to set up response policy on my existing Bind9 server because I'd like to override some of my company public domain to redirect them to our private network ips.

I've followed this tutorial :
https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/set-up-response-policy-zone-rpz-in-bind-resolver-on-debian-ubuntu

However, I'm getting this error for the two domains I'm trying to override :

```
named[17104]: /etc/bind/zones/db.rpz:17: ignoring out-of-zone data (xxx.mydomain1.com)
named[17104]: /etc/bind/zones/db.rpz:19: ignoring out-of-zone data (yyy.mydomain2.com)
named[17104]: (re)loading policy zone 'rpz' changed from 0 to 2 qname, 0 to 0 nsdname, 0 to 0 IP, 0 to 0 NSIP, 0 to 0 CLIENTIP entries
named[17104]: zone rpz/IN: loaded serial 14
```

here's my configuration :
named.conf.local :

```
zone "rpz" {
    type master;
    file "/etc/bind/zones/db.rpz";
    allow-transfer { IP_DNS2; };
};
```

named.conf.options :

```
options {
        ...OPTIONS...
        response-policy {
                zone "rpz";
        };
}
```

/etc/bind/zones/db.rpz :

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     localhost.rpz. root.rpz. (
                              14         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;

@       IN      NS      localhost.rpz.

localhost.rpz.  A       127.0.0.1

xxx.mydomain.com.    A       PRIVATE_IP

yyy.mydomain2.com.      A       PRIVATE_IP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to start over and copy db.empty to db.rpz and add the two domains and now it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIR LHS should NOT end in `.` in RPZ zone file.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/502495)

Comment: Yes, it does. The zone is `rpz` and the names DO NOT belong to it.